# Can I allow a user to persist changes to an HTML page using only JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there a way to persist changes to an HTML page via a simple form?  I have a list of links and would like the user to be able to add, remove and update those links via a simple form.  This site has no database (and cannot have a database).  The site is entirely XHTML and JavaScript (mostly JQuery).  I realize JavaScript is clientside but I was really hoping there is a way to save changes to the XHTML file without jumping into php or jsp.  I'm new at this, please be gentle.

**EDIT:**
Does anyone know of a place to start looking if I were to do this in JSP?  The reason that I specify JSP is that it is my employer's preferred language.  I want to write the user's changes directly to an html (or jsp) file through the use of a simple form.  I have extremely limited JSP experience and would really appreciate someone pointing me to a good tutorial.  I found plenty of tutorials for persisting across session(s) and writing to a database but nothing for saving the HTML (or jsp) back to the server...

Comment: That is really not what JavaScript is designed for...

Comment: - you need to get the data back from the client and re-display a modified html page, this requires some kind of server side work : so yes php et al.

Comment: Persist can mean a lot of things.  Persist through a session or between sessions?

Comment: I meant persist the changes back to the server so that other users could see the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without a server-side language. As you point out, JS is client-only.

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, the [HTML5 storage API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) might work depending on what you want to do. However, if you want to actually change the XHTML document and have that change reflected for *all* users, you *have* to use a server-side language.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems I will be jumping into jsp.

Comment: @grizzljt: Don't be too quick to believe everything you're told. There are client-side-only storage APIs now. That said, jumping into J2EE (not just JSPs) is very liberating.

Comment: Well, there are cookies and there's the HTML5 storage API, but those are per-user and pretty volatile. For *true* persistence, you have to go server-side.

Comment: My impression was that the requirement here was for per-user stuff. Vis-a-vis volatility, from the spec: *"User agents should expire data from the local storage areas only for security reasons or when requested to do so by the user."*. Google's putting a lot of muscle behind web storage (for obvious reasons). None of which changes the fact that in today's world, if the OP *can* use a server (somewhere), that's probably the better option. But if they *can't*... :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to save data client side are cookies, and they might be deleted whenever the user decides, so it's probably not a good idea.

Comment: @shurdoof , there is limit for cookies, we can't store lot of valus, just thought of sharing info ,

Comment: Cookies will also only apply to one specific user.

Comment: @gov, never used cookies so I didn't know that, makes sense though. thanks for the info. Looks like the limit is 4KB per cookie.

Comment: @yes shurdoof, just thought of sharing thats it.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can do is to use cookies, but that would only store the links for each user (i.e. I won't be able to see your links and viceversa).

For any other "stable" change you need a server-side language (e.g. PHP)

Answer (score 1):

Without some kind of server side language you will not be able to update the HTML of a page. Changing the HTML is also rather nasty so since you'll need to use a server side language anyway it would probably be a good idea to store the links in a file and use the server side code to add this to the page on a request.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a way of doing this. It is client side.

But PHP is quite easy, you could just save the data in a .txt file if you do not want to touch databases yet.

Comment: Oh, I'm more than willing to use a database.  My boss said that he doesn't want to have to implement a new database.

Answer (score 1):

Changes need to be persisted somewhere.  If there is no database, there is no where to save those changes.  As Shurdoof mentioned, you can save them in cookies, but if the user has cookies disabled, or if they clear them later, then all the changes will be lost, and this will not be a reliable solution.

Short answer, this is not possible with Javascript/jQuery.

**EDIT**:With HTML 5, you may want to look into [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are your only real hope I believe but they can be deleted at any time (or maybe not even saved in the first place). Try here for information http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 1):

Options I can see if you really can't use your own DB:

1. With newer browsers, you can use the new [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-webstorage-20090423/) standards.
2. If your users are willing to work with you (e.g., install a plug-in from a trusted source) and they're not on Linux, there's [Google Gears](http://gears.google.com/). Some number of people will already have it installed.
3. As everyone's said, you can use cookies. Note that cookies will be limited, both in terms of the size of an individual cookie and in terms of how many cookies you can save for a particular path.
4. This is not likely to be a good user experience, but you could also use bookmarks with really long query strings on them (e.g., the user adds their links, you generate a URL with those links embedded in the query string, and the user bookmarks that resulting URL).
5. Cheating a bit, you could use the [Google Docs Spreadsheet API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/). I say "cheating" because you said the site couldn't have a DB, but maybe I can get away with it if the DB is fully hosted for you and hooked into your users' account rather than yours?